# Prove every convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

I'm not sure how to go about this. I know if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$, then given $\epsilon > 0$:

(1) $\exists N$ such that for $n \geq N$, $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Somehow, I must show:

(2) for large $n,m$, $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$.

I think by (1), we can choose $m > n \geq N$ such that $|a_m - L| < \epsilon$ and $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$. I am not sure how to reconcile these inequalities to get (2) though.

Comment: $|a_m - a_n | \leq |a_m - L| + |a_n - L| \lt \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2$.  Choose $N$ so that the two inequalities are $\lt \epsilon /2$ instead of $\epsilon$.  Since it's "for any epsilon".  That is the triangle inequality by definition of the real norm given.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a non-Cauchy sequence. Then there exist a (fixed) $\varepsilon \gt 0$ so that for any $N$ we can find $s \ge N$ and $t \ge N$ such that $|a_s - a_t| \ge \varepsilon$. We can certainly take $s$ and $t$ so that $a_s \le a_t$.

We can actually construct two subsequences of $\{a_n\}$ by taking the 'next' $N$ to be larger than all the $s ^{\;'}$s and $t ^{\;'}$s seen so far, with the two subsequences satisfying

$\tag 1 \{a_{s_k}\}_{\, k \ge 0} \text{ and } \{a_{t_k}\}_{\, k \ge 0} \text{ with } a_{s_k} + \varepsilon \le a_{t_k}$

Suppose now that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$. Then every subsequence converges to $L$. But if we apply the limit operation to $(1)$, we get

$\qquad L + \varepsilon \le \lim\inf\, a_{t_k} = L = \lim\sup\, a_{t_k}$

which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L.$ For $\epsilon >0$ let $\epsilon'=\epsilon /2$ and let $n_{\epsilon'}\in \Bbb N$ such that $$\forall n\geq n_{\epsilon'}\;(|L-a_n|<\epsilon').$$ Then for all $m,n$ such that $n_{\epsilon'}\leq n\leq m$ we have $$|a_n-a_m|=|(a_n-L)+(L-a_m)|\leq |a_n-L|+|L-a_m|<\epsilon' +\epsilon'=\epsilon.$$

Comment: In the 17th century you could say "$ |L-a_n$| is infinitesimal as $n$ becomes infinitely large. So when $m$ and $n$  become infinitely large, $|a_n-a_m|$ is not more than the sum of the infinitesimals $|a_n-L|, |L-a_m|,$  so $|a_n-a_m|$ becomes infinitesimal."  And you would score 10 out of 10 on a test. Don't do this on an exam.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ iff for any $e>0$ the set $\{n: |a_n-L|\geq e\}$ is finite.  That is, $|a_n-L|$ is as close to $0$ as desired for all but finitely many $n.$  And if $a_n,a_m$ are each  within  $\epsilon /2$  of $L$ then  $a_n,a_m$ must be within $\epsilon$ of each other .

Comment: You should replace "$n_{\epsilon'}\leq n\leq m$" with "$n_{\epsilon'}\leq n \text{ and } n_{\epsilon'}\leq m$".

Comment: @MikeMathMan  . It's logically equivalent

Comment: Yes, so it is. Also, I like your first two comments. The second comment  can stand as a proof, that no doubt Cauchy would give a 10 out of 10.
#mathematicalRigour https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigour#Mathematics

Comment: @MikeMathMan . I dk whether you are familiar with hyper-reals. $\Bbb R$ can be extended to a much larger ordered field $\Bbb R^*$ and with some appropriate definitions,  my 17th-century "proof" can be (verbatim) a modern rigorous proof. But you shouldn't do this as an introduction to the subject